# Stacking arrays

Tags: stacking-symbols

I want to reproduce something called the tower notation:

[image: Example of tower notation]

I have found out that I can make the tables like this:

```
\begin{array}{c|c}
S & S\\ 
S & S\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{DP\bs S}\\
\end{array}
```

But I'm having trouble stacking these items, and then with wrapping everything in parentheses that grow with the content.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built stacking components and then combined them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\bs{\textbackslash}
\def\Sm{S\textsuperscript{$-$}}
\tabcolsep 2pt
\begin{document}
\savestack\blockA{
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
S & \Sm\\ 
\hline
\Sm & \Sm\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{DP}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\savestack\blockB{
\begin{tabular}{c}
$\forall x.[\,]x$\\
\hline
$[\,]$\\
\hline
$x$
\end{tabular}
}

\savestack\blockC{
\begin{tabular}{l|c}
\Sm & \Sm\\ 
\hline
\Sm & \Sm\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{((DP\bs S)/DP)/DP}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\savestack\blockD{
\begin{tabular}{c}
$[\,]$\\
\hline
$[\,]$\\
\hline
\textbf{gave}
\end{tabular}
}

\savestack\blockE{
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\Sm & \Sm\\ 
\hline
\Sm & S\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{DP}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\savestack\blockF{
\begin{tabular}{c}
$[\,]$\\
\hline
$\exists y.[\,]$\\
\hline
$y$
\end{tabular}
}

\savestack\blockG{
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\Sm & \Sm\\ 
\hline
S & S\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{DP}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\savestack\blockH{
\begin{tabular}{c}
$\forall z.[\,]$\\
\hline
$[\,]$\\
\hline
$z$
\end{tabular}
}

\[
\vcenter{\hbox{\Shortstack{\blockA\\no one\\\blockB}}}
\left(\left(
\vcenter{\hbox{\Shortstack{\blockC\\gave\\\blockD}}}
\vcenter{\hbox{\Shortstack{\blockE\\anyone\\\blockF}}}
\right)
\vcenter{\hbox{\Shortstack{\blockG\\everything\\\blockH}}}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]